# How to manage a repository for bootstrap code?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, versioning

I want to have a repository with the code base I will be using for most of my projects, but I'm not sure on how to deal with this.

All I can think of is to just clone it when I start a new project, and then remove the .git or .hg folder (and create it again for the versioning of the new project)

Is there a better way? Maybe something with submodules? The problem is that these files I need can't be in a separate folder, they are the core of the application, for example a Rails instance.

Is there a recommended way for doing this?

Comment: export from Core repo and add to new?

Comment: Fork project without keeping old history?

Comment: My codebase is .gitignore, .hgignore files to include ignore list for a certain programming language

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way would be using [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository).
This is the easiest solution for ["core" files that are needed in each project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649266/6884).

However, a subrepository will be in a subfolder inside your main repository.
You said this:

> The problem is that these files I need can't be in a separate folder, they are the core of the application, for example a Rails instance.

...so I'm not sure if subrepositories are a viable solution for you.

I don't know anything about Rails or about your application, so I can't tell if it's possible in your case to put your "core" files into a subfolder.